# Query table with name and return data with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.1 for a project, but part of this project needs to allow for the user to be able to create custom tables, that hold custom data.  Now i would like to be able to query the data using LINQ and thought for WHERE clauses, i could use DynamicLINQ, but how can i query a table, when all i have is the table name as a string?

For the data that the user creates custom tables for, i will not have a class created.  I would instead have the table itself within SQL, and also a EAV sort of table, that holds details of that table.

Since i also will not have a class for these tables, can i query the data using LINQ?  If so, what kind of object would it return?  Maybe dynamic?

So basically i would like something like this

```
var data = _context.GetTable("MyTable")
    .Where("Name = 'BOB')
    .ToList();
```

Is this possible?  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

No, as name itself says it's entity-framework so it requires entity and relational data with pre-define mapping domain entity. up to entity framework - 6 it is not supported may be in future version 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx.

For your solution I suggest you to use ADO.Net and Enterprise Library that support all ADO.Net functions, so that you can have string query and build it dynamic and execute that query.

Comment: Would this make a difference if each table created had a a particular interface defining some particular fields? ie. Id, Name, Reference.  All other fields would be dynamic

Comment: In entity framework you can't perform any operation without domain entity mapping. And in dynamic table and fields that would not possible so better  you can build your query as string and execute that query.